# How to use scrollRectToVisible:animated?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have tableView and in one of the rows I have a horizontal scrollView and some images(images are in different view of the row), In horizontal scrollView i have added few buttons (10 buttons). when user clicks on any button from scrollView I call `reloadData`. Because I call `reloadData` so horizontal scrollView reloads again with new image Data.  Now I want if user scrolls to end and clicked the last button from the scrollView, user should be able to see that selected button not the first one. I don't know how can i use `scrollRectToVisible:animated` to make this happen.

here is my code for scrollView and adding buttons on it.

```
-(void)addColorFiltersOnView:(UIView *)colorView{       
    if (_colorFilterView) {
        [_colorFilterView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    self.colorFilterView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:colorView.bounds];
    [_colorFilterView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [_colorFilterView setBackgroundColor:samergb(238)];
    [_colorFilterView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

    int addedCount = 0;
    int i=0;

    CGFloat x = 10, y = 5;

    if ([_colorFilters count] < 1) {
        return;
    }

    for (i=0; i<[_colorFilters count] - 1; i++) {

        id item = [_colorFilters objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){

            if ([self.prodVIPDictionary.PDcolor isEqualToString:(NSString*)item] && i != 0) {
                continue;
            }

            NSInteger itemsCount = [[_colorFilters objectAtIndex:i+1] integerValue];

            if (itemsCount  <= 0) {
                break;
            }

            TTTAttributedLabel *itemLabel = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            [itemLabel setNumberOfLines:1];
            [itemLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
            [itemLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];

            if ([_selectedColor isEqualToString:(NSString*)item])
                [itemLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

            [itemLabel setText:[(NSString*)item capitalizedString]];
            [itemLabel setBackgroundColor:samergb(255)];
            itemLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1;
            itemLabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            itemLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
            itemLabel.layer.borderColor = samergb(210).CGColor;
            [itemLabel sizeToFit];
            [_colorFilterView addSubview:itemLabel];

            CGRect itemFrame = itemLabel.frame;
            itemFrame.size.width += 20;
            [itemLabel setFrame:itemFrame];

            UIButton *optionBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, itemLabel.frame.size.width + 6, 26)];
            [optionBtn setTag:[_colorFilters indexOfObject:item]];
            [optionBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(optionColorClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            [_colorFilterView addSubview:optionBtn];

            [itemLabel setFrame:optionBtn.frame];

            if ([_selectedColor isEqualToString:(NSString*)item]) {
                [optionBtn setEnabled:NO];
                [itemLabel setBackgroundColor:[LRUtils lrGreenColor]];
            }

            addedCount ++;

            x += optionBtn.frame.size.width+5;

            if (addedCount >= 20) {
                break;
            }

        }else{
            continue;
        }
    }

    [_colorFilterView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((x + 10),colorView.frame.size.height)];
    [colorView addSubview:_colorFilterView];
}
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. If the user scrolls and clicks the last button, what is actually happening compared to what you want to happen? Is the scrollview going back to the beginning for some reason? Perhaps you should update your question with your `optionColorClicked:` method.

Comment: @rmaddy I have just updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `reloadData`, you could call this method on the Table View:

`- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation`

You would need to create an `NSArray` containing all of the IndexPaths in the Table View *except* for the row with the scroll view and buttons. This way, the scroll view wouldn't get reset.

Comment: That's the one option I have thought but didn't try because scrollView and Image data is in a same cell so even if I use reloadRowsAtIndexPath, ScrollView will get reset. I think there is no other way except making scrollView in a separate cell.